# PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout() not throwing Exception

Tags: java, database, exception

I was trying to set query timeout as 5 seconds but no exception is caught after 5 seconds

````
        preparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(5);
        try{
            return  preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            throw new CustomException(CustomErrorCode.RESPONSE_TIME_OUT,"");
        }
      ```
````

Answer (score 0):

When the timeout is exceeded, it should throw `SQLTimeoutException` and not the regular `SQLException`.

[See more here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery())

Comment: Doesn't SQLTimeoutException derive from SQLException (via SQLTransientException) ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Yes, SQLTimeoutException is a subclass of SQLException which makes it odd that the exception is not caught in his example.